# macOS Installer "Show Files" only "The file listing isn't available"

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild, pkg-file

The Installer has a build-in file browser under file menu. But it only shows "The file listing isn't available".

In the installer log:

```
Installer[82159]: PFPackage::packageWithURL - can't instantiate package: /Users/*/Downloads/Install.pkg
```

Screenshot:

[image: macOS Installer "Show Files" only "The file listing isn't available"]

Structure of the Install.pkg:
[image: Structure of the Install.pkg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the space in the embedded Installer package. Changing "Letter Opener.pkg" to "Letter-Opener.pkg" fixes it.